# Pass dataframe and vector values as argument of function

Tags: r, apply

For each row of a data frame I want to count how many events occur between the date time indicated in the column `start` and `end`.

Please consider the following function

```
calcFreqTimeInterval <- function (startTime, endTime, timestampVector) {
  sum(timestampVector >= startTime & timestampVector <= endTime)
}
```

as argument of the function I want

```
df <- data.frame(start=c("06/11/2013 10:00:00","06/11/2013 17:30:00"), end=c("06/11/2013 11:15:00","06/11/2013 17:45:00"))
timestamp <- as.POSIXlt(c("2013-11-06 10:30:19","2013-11-06 10:32:19","2013-11-06 11:00:19", "2013-11-06 17:40:50","2013-11-06 17:42:50"))
```

respectively. After converting the columns to Posix with

```
df$start <- as.POSIXlt((df$start), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df$end <- as.POSIXlt((df$end), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I would like to obtain as result

```
expectedResult <- c(3,2)
```

I should be able to use `apply` if my arguments were all in the df, but how to use as argument also a vector?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mapply`.  Before that you need to use `POSIXct` class instead of `POSIXlt` class.

```
df <- data.frame(start=c("06/11/2013 10:00:00","06/11/2013 17:30:00"), end=c("06/11/2013 11:15:00","06/11/2013 17:45:00"))
timestamp <- as.POSIXct(c("2013-11-06 10:30:19","2013-11-06 10:32:19","2013-11-06 11:00:19", "2013-11-06 17:40:50","2013-11-06 17:42:50"))

df$start <- as.POSIXct((df$start), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df$end <- as.POSIXct((df$end), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

`mapply` applies `FUN` to the first elements of each ... argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on. Arguments are recycled if necessary. `MoreArgs` is a list of other arguments to `FUN`.

```
mapply(FUN = calcFreqTimeInterval, startTime = df$start, endTime = df$end, MoreArgs = list(timestampVector = timestamp))
## [1] 3 2
```

Comment: but then I get Warning messages:
1: In `>=.default`(timestampVector, startTime) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `<=.default`(timestampVector, endTime) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In `>=.default`(timestampVector, startTime) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In `<=.default`(timestampVector, endTime) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to use `POSIXct` class, not `POSIXlt`.